# Position tooltip based on mouse position

Tags: chart.js

I'm using a stacked bar chart with a default range on the y -axis from 0 - 24. Each stacked bar consists of 6 bars (that go from 0 to 4). If the total size of the stacked bar is small, the user can not read the tooltip because it is always displayed below the mouse pointer.

Is there a way to indicate where tooltip should be displayed (e.g. below the mouse if the upper part of the chart is hovered, above if the lower part of the chart is hovered?

The options that I'm currently using are:

```
$scope.options={
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        type: "time",
                        format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
                        time: {
                            displayFormats: {
                                'millisecond': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'second': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'minute': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'hour': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'day': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'week': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'month': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'quarter': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                                'year': 'M-D', // Sep 4 2015
                            },
                            tooltipFormat: 'M-D'
                        }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks:{
                            min: 0,
                            max: 24
                        }
                }]
        },
            colors: ["rgba(192,216,0,1.0)","rgba(148,64,237,1.0)","rgba(77,167,77,1.0)",
                     "rgba(203,75,75,1.0)","rgba(255,206,123,1.0)","rgba(0,168,240,1.0)"]
    }
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gadeynebram/53q4ddaq/) to explain the problem.

Comment: I need a solution for this as well. Any luck? I'm looking for something like how the tooltip is positioned here: http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav

Answer (score 12):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but it's close:

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor = function(chartElements, coordinates) {
  return coordinates;
};
```

Then in your graph options:

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    position: 'cursor',
    intersect: false
  }
}
```

Comment: I was spamming over with `hover:` option. Thanks a lot for right direction :)

Comment: will you please share live demo in angular, I am little bit confuse to use Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor

Answer (score 7):

like Devon Sams said, you can use this :

```
    Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor = function(chartElements, coordinates) {
      return coordinates;
    };
```

But in your graph options you put the mode on 'label' and intersect on 'true' :

```
    options: {
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'label',
        position: 'cursor',
        intersect: true
      }
    }
```

the tooltip pointer will always be over the chart bar/line in the position of the mouse pointer when hovering the data.

Here is an exemple I made on CodePen : [Link](https://codepen.io/AZIIZoom/pen/dyXYvRJ)

Comment: will you please share live demo in angular, I am little bit confuse to use Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor.

Comment: Hello @jaykhatri, here is an exemple :
https://codepen.io/AZIIZoom/pen/dyXYvRJ

Comment: Thanks @AZIIZ, but this is base of simple HTML version, I am looking for how can i integrate in angular.

will you please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311980/how-can-i-use-chart-tooltip-positioners-cursor-in-angular-ng2-chart

Comment: sorry @jaykhatri , I didn't worked on angular before, I have no idea on how to make this work.