# How can I use Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor in angular ng2 chart?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example

here is working example in js : https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/35081nag/

I want to use this code in my project but am not able to find, how can I use this code.

the working example is done by using chart.js and I want to make it done using ng2-charts, You can see in working example the tooltip is moveable on mouse position, I  want to implement in angular project.

```
Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor = function(chartElements, coordinates) {
      return coordinates;
    };
```

Comment: Can you specify more what you want because I don't see any difference between your code and this working example?

Comment: @RobertGłowacki...  the working example is done by using chart.js and I want to make it done using ng2-charts, You can see in working example the tooltip is moveable on mouse position, I want to implement in angular project.

Comment: as I see your working example there is a tooltip when you mouse over the data

Comment: yes, that same thing, how can I do in angular project?

Comment: this is a working example with a toolip https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng2-charts-toggle-axis-visibility-z7elmq 
this is an angular project, if you want to toggle them off there is code in lines 40-42, what else you want?

Comment: @RobertGłowacki, https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/35081nag/ this is working example what i want to implement in https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-chart-example this example.

https://jsfiddle.net/edicarlos10/35081nag/ in this, you can see when you mouse hover on bars the tooltip moves on mouse position. which is done by using chart.js but i want to make it done using ng2-chart in angular project. i hope you got my point.

Answer (score 4):

you need to import Chart from chart.js

```
import { Chart } from "chart.js";
```

then you can use it in constructor

```
  constructor() {
    Chart.Tooltip.positioners.cursor = (chartElements, coordinates) => {
      return coordinates;
    };
  }
```

and put it in options with name 'cursor'

```
lineChartOptions: any = {
    tooltips: {
      intersect: false,
      position: 'cursor',
      mode: 'index'
    }
  };
```